# Meteor - What is the best process for securing forms and storing sensitive data

Tags: meteor

I'm building my first app with Meteor and I'd like to know the best security measures to take in a couple of situations...

1. How do I ensure users are not submitting commands like drop table to my forms? Do I have to manually sanitize somehow or is this automatically handled?
2. Normally I would use a GET on forms if it asks the user for sensitive information, however I'm confused how Meteor handles inserting items to the db. Is the info submitted through forms secure or is it being passed over somewhere people can it?
3. If I have removed the autopublish and the insecure packages it means users cannot just query for other user information, is that correct?

Sorry, if these are noob questions. I haven't quite wrapped my head around how the security of an app all fits in but any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: I'd recommend watching any meteor videos where [Emily Stark](http://www.youtube.com/user/MeteorVideos/search?query=emily+stark) talks about security. The [Meteor Meets Mallory](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=79uMp-S23MA) talk is especially helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a quick rundown of the basics of securing your meteor app:

1. Transmit everything over HTTPS.
2. Separate your client and server code into their own directories. A great way to keep your server-side secrets safe is to never send them to the client in the first place.
3. Remove the `insecure` package.
4. Remove the `autopublish` package.
5. Add the [audit-argument-checks](http://docs.meteor.com/#auditargumentchecks) package and add [checks](http://docs.meteor.com/#check) to all methods and publish functions.
6. Add the [browser-policy](http://docs.meteor.com/#browserpolicy) package (after completing all of the above).

---

Here are some answers to your questions:

1. If insecure is removed and you don't have any [allow](http://docs.meteor.com/#allow) rules, then users can't remove anything. Regardless, documents on the client can only be removed or updated by id, so you can't drop a collection with a single command.
2. With the proper allow rules specified, then the client can execute an insert/update. Otherwise, you can use a meteor method to have the server perform an insert/update for you. e.g. you can specify a method like `postsInsert` on the server. Messages will be passed between the client and the server in the clear unless you use SSL.
3. Correct. With `autopublish` off, you need to specify which documents are published to the client - otherwise the client will not have read access to any documents.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This answers my questions and will definitely help me secure my app.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your users to perform certain operations, you don't allow them to do so. The only commands your users are able to perform on the database are those you specify : when you remove the insecure package, typing Collection.remove({}); in the browser console won't drop the entire collection, users will have to Meteor.call certain allowed operations (through Meteor.methods) to perform authenticated-only stuff.

Generally, you want the OWNER of a resource to be able to edit/delete it, but other people shouldn't be able to modify it.
If you have an edit form for one of your collection, you will likely have corresponding Meteor.methods to edit/delete it.
Inside a Meteor.method, you can check the passed arguments received from the client to validate data correctness, you can also verify if the call was issued from an allowed user (typically the owner of the document).
Hopefully, Meteor comes with a Match framework to test parameters sent to Meteor.methods.

```
// define a test to check if a document is editable by a certain user
EditableDocument=function(userId){
    return Match.Where(function(documentId){
        var document=Collection.findOne(documentId);
        if(!document){
            throw new Meteor.Error(500,"Document doesn't exist !");
        }
        if(userId!=document.creator._id){
            throw new Meteor.Error(500,"Can't update a document you don't own.");
        }
        return true;
    });
};

Meteor.methods({
    updateCollection:function(documentId,fields){
        check(documentId,EditableDocument(this.userId));
        check(fields,{
            field1:Match.Optional(String),
            field2:Match.OneOf(Number,Boolean),
            field3:Match.Any
        });
        // if the tests pass, do your thing
        ...
    }
});
```

To communicate form data between the client and the server, Meteor uses DDP (Data Distributed Protocol) with a technique known as Remote Method Invocation.
A client can Meteor.call a Meteor.method declared in the server and get a response asynchronously.
This is different from classic form submition manipulation techniques which is done using HTTP, and can use its secure counterpart HTTPS, to encrypt data between a client and the server, avoiding data sniffing issues.
DDP supports data encryption and every *.meteor.com hosted sites are using meteor.com certificate to ensure that all traffic is properly encrypted using SSL.
On your own hosting solution, you will have to handle this yourself though.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-core/a9dPA1-mgXA

After removing autopublish, every server resources won't be published to all clients no more, meaning that one can't just query your collections to get other users documents access.

Be sure to read the docs at least once to fully understand Meteor related aspects of web development.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive reply, this with the other answer really helps me to understand how to secure my app.